# Send text to .bat file that is ran from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, batch-file

I want to start a .bat file from within NodeJS. With that, I would then be able to send messages to that running bat file.

My code:

```js
const childprocess = require("child_process")
const mybat = childprocess.exec("start cmd /c my.bat", () => {
  console.log("bat file has finished")
})

// some time later in another function
mybat.send("text to send")
// within the bat, it would use the new message "text to send" as if you typed and sent a message in the cmd terminal

// ...
mybat.send("a")
// sending any key to complete a PAUSE command which will close the cmd
```

The .send() isn't a working function but hopefully it demonstrates what I'm trying to accomplish. Everything except the send functions works fine.

Comment: The past participle of to run is run!

Answer (score 0):

The following code uses [@rauschma/stringio](https://github.com/rauschma/stringio) to asynchronously write to the stdin of a child process running a shell command:

```
const {streamWrite, streamEnd, onExit} = require('@rauschma/stringio');
const {spawn} = require('child_process');

async function main() {
  const sink = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', 'my.bat'],
    {stdio: ['pipe', process.stdout, process.stderr]}); // (A)

  writeToWritable(sink.stdin); // (B)
  await onExit(sink);

  console.log('bat file has finished');
}
main();

async function writeToWritable(writable) {
  ...
  await streamWrite(writable, 'text to send\n');
  ...
  await streamWrite(writable, 'a');
  ...
  await streamEnd(writable);
}
```

We spawn a separate process, called sink, for the shell command. writeToWritable writes to sink.stdin. It does so asynchronously and pauses via await, to avoid requiring too much buffering.

Observations:

- In line A, we tell spawn() to let us access stdin via sink.stdin ('pipe'). stdout and stderr are forwarded to process.stdin and process.stderr, as previously.
- We don’t await in line B for the writing to finish. Instead, we await until the child process sink is done.